# netcat gcc compile option so that IDA pro can show function name

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I want IDApro show functions name and variables, like: `_readwrite`, `_dolisten` but it only shows `sub_40xxxx` in function window.

How can I edit the compile option to achieve it?

The original Makefile is:

```
CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-DNDEBUG -DWIN32 -D_CONSOLE -DTELNET -DGAPING_SECURITY_HOLE
LDFLAGS=-s -lkernel32 -luser32 -lwsock32 -lwinmm

all: nc.exe

nc.exe: getopt.c doexec.c netcat.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) getopt.c doexec.c netcat.c $(LDFLAGS) -o nc.exe
```

Comment: Euh, it should be able to do so by default. If it can't, then the reason probably is that you `strip`ped the executable.

Comment: stripped the executable?what is it?

Comment: I found nc that can show function name is 2.5 times larger in filesize than mine, maybe it had added addtional debugger info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using `mingw` on Windows. So, the `-s` option in the `LDFLAGS` means that the final binary will be stripped. Just remove this option.

Moreover, you can try to add more debug information in order to help IDAPro to recover as much as possible from the program by adding `-g3` to the `CFLAGS` and by replacing `-DNDEBUG` by `-DDEBUG` (it will also probably add more insightful messages from the software).

At the end you should have something like this:

```
CFLAGS=-g3 -DDEBUG -DWIN32 -D_CONSOLE -DTELNET -DGAPING_SECURITY_HOLE
LDFLAGS=-lkernel32 -luser32 -lwsock32 -lwinmm
```

Just as a side note, you may be answered much more efficiently about question on IDAPro on [RE](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thanks, I tried -g and remove -DNDEBUG, but not solve the problem.

Comment: What if you replace `-DNDEBUG` by `-DDEBUG` ?

Comment: I know ! In fact, you are using mingw, then just remove the `-s` from the `LDFLAGS`. Adding `-g3` and replacing `-DNDEBUG` by `-DDEBUG` will just give you more precise information (it could be quite useful anyway to IDAPro).

Comment: It works!! But -g3 makes the executable super big, I use -g; -s:Omit all symbol information from the output file.

Comment: In fact, the `-g` option can come with a number to indicate the level of information you want to embed in the binary. Default is `-g2`, and `-g3` add everything you might want to trace inside the binary. If you want a lightweight debug binary, just use `-g1`.